# Is there a Python library to handle OWL?

Tags: python, semantic-web, owl

It could be something as big as [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) or something smaller. Do you know anything?

Comment: [tag:owlready].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most people use [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib), but that focuses on RDF, not OWL.

Answer (score 20):

What looks to be the only current and active open source package:

- [FuXi 1.0: A Python-based, bi-directional logical reasoning system for the semantic web](http://code.google.com/p/fuxi/)

This is a Java package but it has a Python console (via Jython):

- [Protégé Script Console](http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/script-console/)

A commercial package that has python support:

- [Python Sesame API Tutorial for AllegroGraph 4.2](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/python-tutorial/python-tutorial-40.html)

Some packages that are admittedly incomplete:

- [OWL SugarView](http://bob.sh/owl)

Some older packages that appear inactive:

- [OWL Logic](http://eulersharp.sourceforge.net/2004/02swap/OWLLogic/owllogic.html)
- [Closed World Machine](http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/doc/cwm.html)
- [RDF Closure](http://www.ivan-herman.net/Misc/2008/owlrl/Doc/RDFClosure-module.html)
- [TRAMP](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/tramp/)
- [sparta](https://github.com/mnot/sparta/)
- [seth](http://seth-scripting.sourceforge.net/)
- [surnia](http://www.w3.org/2003/08/surnia/)

Comment: Really nice findings!  I will have to take a closer look at these and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Indeed nice findings. However, as you stated, most of these packages our somewhat outdated. I will give you +1 one, but I'm afraid these findings didn't address my key question here (=OWL reasoner for Python).

Answer (score 10):

Here is a similar question at answers.semanticweb.com: [Python OWL2 API](https://web.archive.org/web/20160524022731/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/12229/python-owl2-api)
 which references this one: [Is there a tool for reading functional owl syntax in Python?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520005032/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/2352/is-there-a-tool-for-reading-functional-owl-syntax-in-python)
. Answers to both of them mention [InfixOWL](http://code.google.com/p/fuxi/wiki/InfixOwl) which is a part of [FuXi](http://code.google.com/p/fuxi/).

FuXi does not support RDFLib 3, but there is [a ticket as well as some active effort](http://code.google.com/p/fuxi/issues/detail?id=4) for making that happen. If you wish to use FuXi right away, you can always switch from RDFLib to [layercake](http://code.google.com/p/python-dlp/wiki/LayerCakePythonDivergence) ("an RDFLib fork readily compatible with FuXi").

Comment: Very nice. What I find annoying is that FuXi is not compatible with `rdflib 3`. Originally this lead me to think that FuXi is not actively developed, but guess I was wrong there. Very good finding!

Comment: Yep. FuXi on layercake was the missing solution I was just looking for. Thanks! +100

Comment: I think this effort on github for supportng fuxi with rdflib 3.+ seems good https://github.com/RDFLib/FuXi